# Match Dataframe Categorical Variables in vector Spark Scala

Tags: scala, vector, apache-spark, dataframe, machine-learning

I have been trying to follow the stack overflow example about creating dataframes for machine learning ml library in spark scala.

[How to create correct data frame for classification in Spark ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028806/how-to-create-correct-data-frame-for-classification-in-spark-ml)

However, I cannot get the matching udf to work.

> Syntax: "kinds of the type arguments (Vector,Int,Int,String,String) do
>   not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type RT,type
>   A1,type A2,type A3,type A4). Vector's type parameters do not match
>   type RT's expected parameters: type Vector has one type parameter, but
>   type RT has none"

I need to create a dataframe to input into the logistic regression library. Source sample data example has:

```
Source, Amount, Account, Fraud
CACC1, 9120.50, 999, 0
CACC2, 3897.25, 999, 0
AMXCC1, -523, 999, 0
MASCC2, -8723.15, 999, 0
```

I suppose my desired output is:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|           features|label|
+-------------------+-----+
|[1.0,9120.50,999]  |  0.0|
|[1.0,3897.25,999]  |  0.0|
|[2.0,-523.00,999]  |  0.0|
|[0.0,-8723.15,999] |  0.0|
+-------------------+-----+
```

So far I have:

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("select * from prediction_test")
val df_2 = df.select("source","amount","account")

val toVec3 = udf[Vector,String,Int,Int] { (a,b,c) => 
  val e3 = c match {
    case "MASCC2" => 0
    case "CACC1" => 1
    case "AMXCC1" => 2
  }
  Vectors.dense(e1, b, c) 
}

val encodeLabel = udf[Double, Int](_match{case "0" => 0.0 case "1" => 1.0})

val df_3 = df_2.withColumn("features", toVec3(df_2("source"),df_2("amount"),df_2("account")).withColumn("label", encodeLabel(df("fraud"))).select("features","label")
```

[How to create correct data frame for classification in Spark ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028806/how-to-create-correct-data-frame-for-classification-in-spark-ml)

Comment: You are defining your udf with 3 input column parameters and given it 4

Comment: Sorry made an edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using Spark 2.3.1 I suggest following codes for classification ready Spark ML Pipeline. If you want to include classification object into Pipeline you need to just add it where I point out. ClassificationPipeline returns a PipelineModel. Once you transform this model you can get a classification ready columns named features and label.

```
// Handles categorical features
 def stringIndexerPipeline(inputCol: String): (Pipeline, String) = {
      val indexer = new StringIndexer()
        .setHandleInvalid("skip")
        .setInputCol(inputCol)
        .setOutputCol(inputCol + "_indexed")
      val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(indexer))
      (pipeline, inputCol + "_indexed")
    }

// Classification Pipeline Function
def ClassificationPipeline(df:DataFrame): PipelineModel = {

  // Preprocessing categorical features
  val (SourcePipeline, Source_indexed) = stringIndexerPipeline("Source")

  // Use StringIndexer output as input for OneHotEncoderEstimator
  val oneHotEncoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator()
    //.setDropLast(true)
    //.setHandleInvalid("skip")
    .setInputCols(Array("Source_indexed"))
    .setOutputCols(Array("Source_indexedVec"))


  // Gather features that will be pass through pipeline
  val inputCols = oneHotEncoder.getOutputCols ++ Array("Amount","Account")

  // Put all inputs in a column as a vector
  val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(inputCols)
    .setOutputCol("featureVector")

  // Scale vector column
  val standartScaler = new StandardScaler()
    .setInputCol("featureVector")
    .setOutputCol("features")
    .setWithStd(true)
    .setWithMean(false)

  // Create stringindexer for label col
  val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().
    setHandleInvalid("skip").
    setInputCol("Fraud").
    setOutputCol("label")

  // create classification object in here 
  // val classificationObject = new ....


  // Create a pipeline
  val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(
    Array(SourcePipeline, oneHotEncoder, vectorAssembler, standartScaler, labelIndexer/*, classificationObject*/))
  pipeline.fit(df)



   }

val pipelineModel = ClassificationPipeline(df)

val transformedDF = pipelineModel.transform(df)
```